# Parameters in stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How many types of parameters are there in a stored procedures and what are they?
Thanks in advance.

And can we delete a table using view? I think yes but in what situation we can't delete it if there are no trigger associated with that table. I mean to say i need to delete a table which has no trigger associated with it using view, in which case i can't delete it?

Comment: Probably you have to ask 2 separated questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically three types of parameters for stored procedures:

- Input
- Output
- InputOutput

Is that what you're looking for??

Also, I don't totally understand what you're asking with your second question? You want to "delete a table" ?? You don't delete tables - you DROP tables. And you can't use a view to drop a table..... or do you mean: can you delete rows from a table through a view?

SQL Server views can indeed be used to modify data - to a certain degree, and by obeying a certain set of rules. Read more about that on MSDN under [Modifying Data Through a View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx).